# Creating CSS/Javascript/jQuery 'like heart'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel

I'm trying to create a button like the twitter heart, but I can't seem to get the JS/CSS to work properly (or I'm doing this incorrectly). Whenever a post is liked I want [this](https://i.gyazo.com/d38552d5fd30c55a967c64dbf27a8fc2.gif) animation to play, FYI: I have fixed the problem that causes all of them to animate at the same time. When a post is displayed that the user already liked I want it to be a solid red color (like at the end of the animation). When a post hasn't been liked by a user yet, I want it to be a solid grey color (like at the beginning of the animation). Below you can find my Javascript, CSS, & HTML. I'm using Laravel as the framework for my project as well as using their template engine, blade, to parse the `@if`s.

JavaScript

```
$('.like').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    postId = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    var isLike = e.target.previousElementSibling == null;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
    }).done(function() {
        if(isLike) {
            if ($(e.target).css('background-position', 'right')) {
                $(e.target).removeClass('heartAnimation');
                $(e.target).addClass('heart');
            } else if ($(e.target).css('background-position', 'left')) {
                $(e.target).addClass('heartAnimation');
            }
            //Change page
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.heart{
    background: url('http://localhost:8079/uncaughterror/public/src/img/web_heart_animation.png');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px; width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: -16px;
    bottom: -16px;
    background-size:1450px;
}

.heart:hover {
    background-position: right;
}

.interaction {
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes heartBlast {
    0% {background-position: left;}
    100% {background-position: right;}
}

@keyframes heartBlast {
    0% {background-position: left;}
    100% {background-position: right;}
}

.heartAnimation {
    -webkit-animation-name: heartBlast;
    animation-name: heartBlast;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(28);
    animation-timing-function: steps(28);
    background-position: right;
}
```

Laravel markup

```
@if(Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('like', '1')->first())
    <a href="#" class="like heart" style="background-position: right;"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
@else
    <a href="#" class="like heart"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
@endif
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/recreating-the-twitter-heart-animation/

Comment: What is expected result of `if ($(e.target).css('background-position', 'right'))` ,`else if ($(e.target).css('background-position', 'left'))`?

Comment: @makshh I have the actual animation done, I need to find a way to check if the animation needs to be played or not.

Comment: if ($(e.target).css('background-position', 'right')) checks if the heart is red, in other words the post has been liked. else if ($(e.target).css('background-position', 'left')) checks if the heart is grey, or the post has not been liked. @guest271314

Comment: What does `console.log($(e.target).css('background-position', 'right'))` log at `console`?

Comment: `Object { context: <a.like.heart>, length: 1, 1 more… }`, the `1 more` is the JavaScript `_proto_` of the object. @guest271314

Comment: `if` expects a `Boolean` value

Comment: does this work still? the animation didnt work for me using the code verbatim or the snippet fix below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `if` statement.

```
if ($(e.target).css('background-position') === 'right') {
  $(e.target).removeClass('heartAnimation');
  $(e.target).addClass('heart');
} else if ($(e.target).css('background-position') === 'left') {
  $(e.target).addClass('heartAnimation');
}
```